# Is there the better way to get countdowntimer?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im in the very beggining of gamedeveloping and here is my countdown timer. I tried to make countdown timer for myself in Unity for Im in love with speedcubing and I decided to make this simple countdown timer, maybe not that simple, but.

Here I was gonna make all sort of things like save the best result, and every time when I break my own best time out I wanted to store it and make this swap my last record time.

I wanted to make the timer count an average time between 5 attempts and between 12 as well. But I'm still not able to make my timer keep white color when I just stop it(it becomes red every space press).

Please, for all the Gods' sake take a simple look on this, I don't understand how to use OOP or something else to improve this unreadable script. My timer still doesn't remove the records time when I click the ResetAll button. Only technically it does, but on the screen they still stay.

I think, that is so bad example, how to make countdown timer, and I wanna improve my skill in programming. Please. There must be the better way to make this.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using TMPro;
using Michsky.UI.ModernUIPack;

public class CountDownTimer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool timerEnabled = false;

    public static float countDownTimer = 0f;
    public float timeBetweenCount = 0f;

    public TextMeshProUGUI[] attemts5 = new TextMeshProUGUI[5];
    public TextMeshProUGUI[] attemts12 = new TextMeshProUGUI[12];

    public TextMeshProUGUI averageOfFiveText;
    public TextMeshProUGUI averageOfTwelveText;

    private Color redForTimer = new Color(1f, 0f, 0f);
    private Color greenForTimer = new Color(0f, 1f, 0f);
    private Color transparent;

    private int quantity5;

    public TextMeshProUGUI timerText;

    public Image prepareUI;

    public List<float> records = new List<float>();
    private float averageOfFive;
    private float averageOfTwelve;

    private void Start() 
    {
        transparent.a = 0f;
        redForTimer.a = 0.2f;
        greenForTimer.a = 0.3f;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if(timerEnabled)
        {
            ProgressBar.isOn = true;
        }

        else if(!timerEnabled)
        {
            ProgressBar.isOn = false;
        }

        

        timerText.text = countDownTimer.ToString("0.00"); 

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            PrepareToCount();
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            if(records.Count != 0 && records.Count <= 5)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < records.Count; i++)
                {
                    attemts5[i].text = i + 1 + ": " + records[i].ToString("0.00");                   
                }
            }

            if(records.Count != 0 && records.Count <= 12)
            for (int i = 0; i < records.Count; i++)
            {
                attemts12[i].text = i + 1 + ": " + records[i].ToString("0.00"); 
            }

            if(timeBetweenCount < 1f)
            {
                prepareUI.color = transparent;
                timeBetweenCount = 0f;               
            }

            if (timeBetweenCount >= 1f)
            {
                StartTimer();
                timeBetweenCount = 0f;
                countDownTimer = 0f;
            }
        }

        if(timerEnabled == true)
        {
            countDownTimer += Time.deltaTime; 

            if (countDownTimer >= .5f)
            {
                if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
                {                  
                    StopTimer();
                    SaveTime();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //Here i wanna reset all the variables by pressing the button

    public void ResetAll()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < records.Count; i++)
        {           
            records.Clear();
        }
    }

    //Here I wanna clear only last variable by pressing the button

    public void ResetLast()
    {

    }

    //Try to save all the times and show average between 5 and 12 on the screen
    private void SaveTime()
    {          
        records.Add(countDownTimer);

        if(records.Count >= 5)
        {
            averageOfFive = records[0] + records[1] + records[2] + records[3] + records[4];
            averageOfFive /= 5f;          
            Debug.Log(averageOfFive);
            averageOfFiveText.text = "AVERAGE: " + averageOfFive.ToString("0.00");

        }
        if(records.Count >= 12)
        {
            averageOfTwelve = records[0] + records[1] + records[2] + records[3] + records[4] + records[5] + records[6] + records[7] + records[8] + records[9] + records[10] + records[11];
            averageOfTwelve /= 12f;
            averageOfTwelveText.text = "AVERAGE: " + averageOfTwelve.ToString("0.00");
        }
        
    }

    private void StopTimer()
    {
        timerEnabled = false;
    }

    private void StartTimer()
    {
        

        prepareUI.color = transparent;
        //timerText.color = Color.white;
        timerEnabled = true;
    }

    private void PrepareToCount()
    {
        if(!timerEnabled)
        {
            prepareUI.color = redForTimer;
        }

        timeBetweenCount += Time.deltaTime;

        if(timeBetweenCount >= 1f)
        {
            prepareUI.color = greenForTimer;
            //timerText.color = Color.yellow;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not a specific question and not a good fit for StackOverflow. Try Googling "unity countdown timer". There are loads of solutions and loads of video tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

First, sorry for my poor English. I'm not a native English Speaker.

I think you thinking too complicated, I don't want to discussion the color issue,
seems like you just put it on the wrong location.

I think you don't need two Arrays to store the best of 5 scores or 12.

You can simply use a Array to do the same thing.

And the `List` I assume you just want to store the all attempts, right?

if you don't care about which times you store the score, you can just using the `Sort()` and `Reverse()`

Here is my Example

```
public float StartTime = 10.0f;
public static int bestTimes = 12;

public TextMesh timerText;
public float[] bestRerord = new float[bestTimes];
public List<float> TotalRecord = new List<float>();

private float nowTime;
private bool isCounting = false;

void Start()
{
    nowTime = StartTime;
    timerText.text = "Time : " + nowTime.ToString("0.00");
}

void Update()
{
    PressSpace();
    if (isCounting)
    {
        CountingTime();
    }
    timerText.text = "Time:" + nowTime.ToString("0.00");
}

void CountingTime()
{ 
    nowTime -= Time.deltaTime;
    if (nowTime <= 0f)
    {
        nowTime = 0f;
        Debug.Log("Time's up");
        //You can also store the time here;
    }
}

void PressSpace()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {//every time you press space key  let Timer Stop or Continue count down(if you don't wanna reset timer)
        isCounting = !isCounting;
    }
    if (nowTime!= StartTime &&  !isCounting)//it means you have time to  record now
    {
        RecordTime(nowTime);
    }
}
void RecordTime(float iTime)
{
    TotalRecord.Add(iTime);
    nowTime = StartTime;  //Reset nowTime every times you record
    SortingTotalRecordAndStore();
}
void SortingTotalRecordAndStore()
{
    int num = TotalRecord.Count;
    if (num > bestTimes) num = bestTimes;

    //Accroding which way you want to present
    TotalRecord.Sort();//etc:1,2,3  
    TotalRecord.Reverse();//etc,3,2,1

    for (int i = 0;  i < num; i++)// it mean it only store the best records you have
    {
        bestRerord[i] = TotalRecord[i];
    }
}
```

and you also talk about you only reset the record in code not on screen,it might be just forgot to update the new record on the screen I think.

In the end, I believe you can handle the average of times calculate by you own.

P.s I don't know if you've noticed, you have a Unassigned variable int `quantity5`

Regards.